# Override SyliusWebBundle Backend menu

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3, sylius

I use Sylius Standard edition for my project. I want to extend it with some features, so I have created new Models and added them via SyliusResourceBundle. Now I want to add them to Backend main menu. How to achieve this? I guess I shouldn't change Menu in SyliusWebBundle but somehow override it, right? As all other things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you extended SyliusWebBundle. You can extend `Sylius\Bundle\WebBundle\Menu\BackendMenuBuilder` to `Tom\Bundle\WebBundle\Menu\BackendMenuBuilder` and change parameter

```
<parameter key="sylius.menu_builder.backend.class">Sylius\Bundle\WebBundle\Menu\BackendMenuBuilder</parameter>
```

to

```
<parameter key="sylius.menu_builder.backend.class">Tom\Bundle\WebBundle\Menu\BackendMenuBuilder</parameter>
```